# Data View Webpart

Tags: powershell, data-view-web-part

I've read so many good things about Data View Webparts and would love to use one in a pagelayout I have developed.

The issue is, SharePoint Designer has been locked down and I have no access to the server files.

So my questions is - is it posisble to use the features of the DVWP only using notepad?

I would like to use this instead of using a Content Query Webpart that refers to my custom xsl.

hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DVWP in a notepad (*.webpart file) and upload it in webpart gallery.
But it will be too difficult.

A better way is to create and customize a DataView in SharePoint designer on a site where you have access. Then you can export the webpart to a *.webpart file. After that you need to make small changes (like updating list GUIDS) which you can do in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

you could use powershell to create a new instance of a dvwp. configure all the settings via powershell. get the instance of a page, access the webpart manager of that page, add the newly created dataview to the page using the zoneid, and zoneindex you desire.

Example

```
    SPFile file = web.GetFile("Page url");   // e.g. /sites/asite/default.aspx
    SPLimitedWebPartManager lwpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    SPLimitedWebPartCollection webParts = lwpm.WebParts;
```

[DataViewWebpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataviewwebpart.aspx)

Give this a try if you getstuck i can help you out

Comment: If you can run powershell, you might as well just log in to the server and give yourself Designer access:)